# Making a user database for websocket chat app

Tags: database, websocket

I'm trying to build simple chat app using websockets. Is it even possible to make a user database for websockets, and have it shown in a dynamic ListView as contact list (regardless if they are online or not)?
Then I could open a room for only those users I click specifically, that are in my user database.

I would use SurfaceView to share data via websockets, like a Whiteboard.